# Scala: On strange behavior of `foldLeft`

Tags: scala

Define:

```
val a = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Consider the following line with `foldLeft`:

```
a.foldLeft(""){case (num, sum) => sum + (num.toString + "-")}
```

My expectation was that the program is going to do:

((((( "7-" +  "6-" ) + "5-" ) + "4-" ) + "3-" ) + "2-" ) + "1-"

which is `7-6-5-4-3-2-1-`

But what I get is: `7654321-------`. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed up the parameters to `foldLeft`. Check the documentation for [`List.foldLeft`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@foldLeft[B](z:B)(f:(B,A)=%3EB):B). Note that the `z` "zero" value has the same type as the *second* parameter in the function argument, not the first.

This should work closer to expected:

```
a.foldLeft(""){case (sum, num) => sum + (num.toString + "-")}
// res0: String = 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-
```

However, if you want the numbers in reverse-order, then you might want to use `foldRight`. Maybe this is actually what you were going for in the first place (notice that the arguments `num` and `sum` are in the same order you gave):

```
a.foldRight(""){case (num, sum) => sum + (num.toString + "-")}
// res1: String = 7-6-5-4-3-2-1-
```

Answer (score 1):

From your expectation, I expect you expected `foldRight` behavior:

```
scala> val a = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> a.foldRight(""){case (num, sum) => sum + (num.toString + "-")}
res0: String = 7-6-5-4-3-2-1-
```